# Automating interactive input in shell

Tags: shell, oracle11g, ksh

I'm trying shell script to automatically accept value as Y when prompted in script but somehow it always say "Operation cancelled at user request".  The `nid` command is an Oracle utility DBNEWID for changing a database name.

Any idea on how to accept Y in below function?
Function logs into database and changes name.

```
function rename_db {
nid target=SYS/"as sysdba" DBNAME=newdb << EOD
Y
EOD
}
```

> Runtime output:
>
> Change db ID and name to newdb? (Y/[N]) =>
>
> Operation cancelled at user
> request

Comment: Can you try following: `echo 'Y' | nid target=SYS/"as sysdba" DBNAME=newdb`

Comment: @gotuskar still receives same "Operation cancelled at user request"

Comment: `printf "Y\r\n" | nid ...` ? good luck.

Comment: Is the stdin flushed by nid? Maybe you can start nid and let the Y being streamed few seconds later: `(sleep 3; echo "Y") | (echo start; while read x; do  echo $x; done)`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and different variations to accept Y, somehow it didn't work. While reading more about nid I found out there is a parameter LOGFILE which if used accepts Y as automatically e.g. `nid target=sys/"as sysdba" dbname=old_db logfile=rename.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below, if we use logfile then it will accept Y as the default and never prompts.

e.g. `nid target=sys/"as sysdba" dbname=old_db logfile=rename.log`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `expect` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) installed? You would want to use that which is designed for this sort of thing.